# How to execute PASTE command with sequence number?

Tags: bash, scripts, paste

I have a folder with 50000 files (file1, file2 ... file49999, file50000) and I need to execute this command: paste file{1..3000} > 1output.txt. It works fine if I paste it in the shell and execute it.

To avoid chainging all the time the sequence number, I tried to create a for loop.

```
bash# x=1; y=3000; for i in {1..50000}; do paste file{$x..$y} > output.txt; x=$((x+3000)); y=$((y+3000)); done
```

Output:

```
paste file{1..3000} > 1output
paste file{3001..6000} > 2output.txt
paste file{6001..9000} > 3output.txt
paste file{9001..12000} > 4output.txt
paste file{12001..15000} > 5output.txt
paste file{15001..18000} > 6output.txt
paste file{18001..21000} > 7output.txt
paste file{21001..24000} > 8output.txt
paste file{24001..27000} > 9output.txt
paste file{27001..30000} > 10output.txt
paste file{30001..33000} > 11output.txt
....
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence) - personally I would avoid the accepted answer (using `eval`) and instead use `seq` or C-style loops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glenn.
Can you explain what (seq -f "file%.0f" $i $((i + inc))) does?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on steeldriver's comment:

```bsh
inc=3000
for ((i = 1, k = 1; i <= 50000; i += inc, k += 1)); do
  readarray -t files < <(seq -f "file%.0f" $i $((i + inc)))
  paste "${files[@]}" > "${k}output.txt"
done
```